# LockManager - idea and API

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, concurrency, locking

I want to develop a LockManager which can lock many variables atones and avoid deadlocks. For example the following piece of code:

long amount = …

```
//two bank accounts
final BankAccount ba1 = ...
final BankAccount ba2 = ...
synchronized(ba1, ba2){
    ba1.transfer(amount , ba2);
}
```

can be replaced by:

```
<!-- language: java -->
//two bank accounts
final BankAccount ba1 = ...
final BankAccount ba2 = ...

//synchronize bank accounts
final LockManager<Object> lockManager = …
synchronizer.synchronize(   ba1, LockMode.Write, 
                            ba2, LockMode.Write, 
                            new Transaction<Object>(){
                                @Override
                                public void execute() {
                                    ...
                                    ba1.transfer(amount , ba2);
                                }

                            } );
```

I need your opinion about the idea and proposed API.

Thank you for your feedback with Best Regards
Andrej

Comment: What would you say is the advantage in your proposed solution?

Comment: Using multiple threads is about improving performance.  When considering such a solution you need to make sure that using multiple threads is still faster than the much simpler single threaded solution.

Comment: Hi,
 I want to implement a graph based Protocol. I hope by using LockManager multi-thread programming becomes simpler and developing costs becomes lower (advantage). 
The performance of such programs wouldn’t be like real fine grained locking software, but a lot faster than in a single thread program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single `lock` object, `synchronize` around it during all operation on required objects:

```
class BankProcessing {
  Object bankLock = new Object();

  void transferAtoB(BankAccount a, BankAccount b) {
    synchronize(bankLock) {
      a.transfer(amount, b);
    }
  }


  void deduct(BankAccount a, int amount) {
    synchronize(bankLock) {
      a.deduct(amount);
    }
  }
}
```

But you MUST ensure that all updates on `BankAccounts` are happening inside one place i.e. `BankProcessing` using same `lock` object i.e. `bankLock`. This has downside of slowness for example call to `deduct` will block call to `transfer` etc. But this slowness might be worth handling bank-transfers.

Comment: LockManager should schedule many locks and supported something like fine-grained locking. I hope this would give a better performance compared to global lock.

Best Regards
Andrej